# Simplification and numerical evaluation differ substantially

Tags: simplifying-expressions, numerical-value

My question is very simple. I am trying to simplify an expression that I was expecting to be vanishing. However, If I numerically evaluate the expression (for large values of one parameter) I find 1, whereas if I simplify it I get 0, see the picture

[image]

Here's the code to reproduce it

```
(m Sqrt[P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2]] - Sqrt[-P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2]] (P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2])) 1/Sqrt[P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2]] /. m -> 1 /. P -> 10^8 // N
(m Sqrt[P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2]] - Sqrt[-P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2]] (P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2])) 1/Sqrt[P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2]] // Simplify[#, {m > 0, P > 0}] &
```

What's happening?

Equivalently, I have rescaled $m\rightarrow x P$ and try to take the $x\rightarrow 0^+$ limit. I get the error `"Unable to determine whether expressions .... are equal to zero. Assuming they are."` 
[image]

Here's the code

```
(m Sqrt[P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2]] - Sqrt[-P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2]] (P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2])) 1/Sqrt[P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2]] /. m -> x P // Simplify[#, P > 0] &
Limit[x - Sqrt[(-1 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])/(1 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])] (1 + Sqrt[1 + x^2]), x -> 0,Direction -> "FromAbove"]
```

This is strange because if I FullySimplify the expression under the limit, I get 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks as though when the parameters become very large, machine-precision arithmetic becomes insufficient to maintain accuracy. With arbitrary precision arithmetic, the answer is consistently indistinguishable from 0.

Comment: @eyorble yes, this is what I thought as well - but shouldn't Mathematica give a Warning message somehow?

Comment: Machine precision has no precision tracking capabilities, so while it probably should from a pure correctness standpoint, there's no real way for it to do so without compromising the speed of machine precision calculations and/or making unsafe assumptions about the accuracy of machine precision input.

Comment: Just as a side comment, to test whether an numeric algebraic expression is zero or not, `PossibleZeroQ`  with the option `Method->"ExactAlgebraics"` is quite powerful. It can handle very large expressions and quickly return an exact answer, even if functions like `Simplify` fail.
Also, if an algebraic expression is non-zero, `RootReduce` tends to be much more efficient at simplification than `Simplify`.

Comment: @Hausdorff thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your expression:

[image]

Obviously, this needs more than machine precision. And you do not get an error message, because with machine arithmetic there is no precision tracking. If you want to increase the precision, e.g. 20 digits, you get:

```
N[(m Sqrt[P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2]] - 
      Sqrt[-P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2]] (P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2])) 1/
     Sqrt[P + Sqrt[m^2 + P^2]] /. m -> 1 /. P -> 10^8, 20]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! but what about the warning message with the limit?

Comment: Try: `GenerateConditions -> Automatic`

Comment: Thanks! It returns the same warning

Comment: I think it is a bug of Limit, because : `Simplify[x - 
  Sqrt[(-1 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])/(1 + Sqrt[1 + x^2])] (1 + Sqrt[1 + x^2]), 
 x > 0]` gives zero. And `Limit` should realize this. Please report it to Wolfram.